# Handling custom subdomain with AWS SES events

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

AWS SES has a new feature where the service will transform links to support  open/click analytics.

[image: Custom domain]

It's not clear from the docs how to handle your own subdomain. Trying this, it seems to transform into a URL where the original URL is escaped as the path, with "cr0" before it and a unique string after, e.g. https://example.com/123 is included in the email as https://mail-subdomain.example.com/cr0/http%3A//example.com/123/long-unique-id-string. But there's no info I can find about how to configure this domain, e.g. should the DNS be pointed to AWS servers using a CNAME?

Answer (score 3):

[I found the answer here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/configure-custom-open-click-domains.html).

It's simply a matter of creating the new subdomain with CNAME record pointing to one of AWS's servers (the servers are listed on that page).

Since the domain's DNS is managed by Cloudflare, I created the subdomain with that CNAME and with the config in my question above, it "just worked". SES handles the redirect itself, so there's no need to configure your own web server or set up any Page Rules on Cloudflare etc. Just make sure your emails include the SES custom header for your configuration set.

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks.